# Swift instance property vs methods: lowercased() vs capitalized

Tags: swift, methods, properties

I am a bit confused here, for some reason I cannot call `capitalized` and `lowercased` the same way, even though both should be Instance Properties:

```
var aString = "a lowercased string" 
aString = aString.capitalized

var anotherString = "A CAPITALIZED STRING!" 
anotherString.lowercased()
```

I cannot do `lowercased` or `capitalized()`

When looking at the API Reference from Apple, I can find that

- lowercased(with:) is an [Instance Method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1690796-lowercased)
- lowercased is a [Instance Property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1408467-lowercased)
- capitalized is an [Instance Property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1642976-capitalized)

So I would think that I can call `lowercased` or `lowercased()` since it is both a method and a property, but I cannot.
This confused me, since I don't seem to understand when/how methods are being called in swift.

Any suggestion on where I can read up on this?

Comment: `lowercased()` is an instance method, and `capitalized` is a computed property.

Comment: yea I get that, but there seems to be an instance property https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1408467-lowercased 'lowercased', too, but for some reason I cannot use it the same as 'capitalized'

Comment: I can't find `capitalized` in string.

Comment: `NSString` has a lowercased property, not `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences between Foundation `NSString` and Swift Library `String`:

- The property `lowercased` belongs to `NSString`.
- The function `lowercased()` belongs to `String`.

But

- Both `String` and `NSString` contain the property `capitalized`.
- Both `String` and `NSString` respond to `lowercased(with:)`.
- There is no *method / function* `capitalized()`.

Comment: thanks! I got confused by the nav bar on the right hand side of apple's developer site where I can switch between objective c and swift. I realize now I have to use the top nav bar to switch from NSString to String